# Pass Datetime/Timestamp from PHP to Javascript by echo

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, timestamp

How can I pass a datetime/timestamp from PHP to javascript. The following does not appear to work:

```
startLive = new Date(<?php echo date("U", strtotime($start_date)); ?>);
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as Where are you writing this line ? Within a Jvascript script tag or somewhere else, if you can share a little more code, I might be able to guide you better.

Comment: you'll need to put `"` as the timestamp is a string

Comment: @ChasingDeath: Sure, `date` returns a string in PHP, but specifying the format as "U", really it's an integer value (even though the variable type is `string`). Javascript still takes it as an integer, so that's not the problem. Really, I think the only problem here is that he needs to multiply it by 1000 to convert it to milliseconds.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
startLive = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($start_date)*1000; ?>);
```

Explanation:

PHP's [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function returns a Unix timestamp (seconds since 1-1-1970 at midnight).

Javascript's [`Date()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) function can be instantiated by specifying *milliseconds* since 1-1-1970 at midnight.

So multiply seconds by 1000 and you get milliseconds, which you can use in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I think that very simple and more universal solution would be

```
var dateTime = <?php echo date('c', strtotime($yourDateTime)) ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you, that made my life very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
startLive = new Date("<?php echo date("F d, Y G:i:s",strtotime($start_date)); ?>");
```

this will sort your problem

Explanation:

[Check Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)