# PHP date outputs are the same using formatString in fooTable

Tags: javascript, php, footable

I am having problem to the footable because whenever i use the data-format-string in footable the output becomes the same.

```
 <table id="table" data-paging="true" data-sorting="true">
 <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-name="date_from" data-type="date" data-format-string="MMM DD YYYY">Date</th>
         <th data-name="title">Title</th>
         <th data-name="venue">Venue</th>
        <th data-name="activity_id">View</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
           $myqry=$db->prepare("SELECT activity_id,date_from,title,venue FROM activity" );
           $myqry->execute();
           $anotherarray=array();
           while($myqr=$myqry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 echo '<tr><td>'.$myqr['date_from'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$myqr['title'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$myqr['venue'].'</td>
                 <td><a href="view_act.php?actvid='.$myqr['activity_id'].'">View</a></td></tr>';
           }                              
       ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

**What I expect:**

[image: this is i expect to see in my date column]

**What I get:**

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: Welcome! You might want to include images that are mostly text as just text in the body of your post. Failing that, add an exclamation point in front of each of 'em `![description][1]` to make it easier for people to answer your question. Cheers!

Comment: oh okay, im just new here, thanks for the suggestion .
however i cant post images due to the lack of reputation

Comment: Ah, I see. I should be able to make it inline by editing :)

Comment: Wow! we can do that huh? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this question.  I converted my date using strtotime then multiplied it by 1 milliseconds. My reference was 
[Pass Datetime/Timestamp from PHP to Javascript by echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233080/pass-datetime-timestamp-from-php-to-javascript-by-echo) the one that Travesty3 answered.
This is my php code now

```
<?php
    $myqry=$db->prepare("SELECT activity_id,date_from,title,venue FROM activity" );
    $myqry->execute();
    while($myqr=$myqry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $mydate=strtotime($myqr['date_from'])*1000;
      echo '<tr><td data-value="'.$mydate.'"></td>
          <td>'.$myqr['title'].'</td>
          <td>'.$myqr['venue'].'</td>
          <td><a href="proc_view_act.php?actvid='.$myqr['activity_id'].'">View</a></td></tr>';
    }
```

?>